# Magento 2 Theme Install Process?

Tags: magento

I am trying to find the way for installing a theme in Magento 2.0. After some research I am not able to find a solution for installing the theme in an older version. We use the key in Connect Manager but Magento 2.0 doesn't give That option in its version. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it more readable. Please do not use Title Case unnecessarily. Keep your sentences small and simple and use punctuation marks such as commas and fullstops. I would recommend you to add more details on what you have tried, what you have found in your research and anything that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use magento1 module key in magento 2.0. you need to create custom theme in magento 2.0 than check below link

[Magento 2.0 custom theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-general.html)

Comment: yes...Magento 1 and magento 2 both File structure are different.so can't use magento1 key in magento 2.0